# What is the right way to create/write a large file in java that are generated by a user?

Tags: java

I have looked at examples that tell best practices for file write/create operations but have not seen an example that takes into consideration my requirements. I have to create a class which reads the contents of 1 file, does some data transformation, and then write the transformed contents to a different file then sends the file to a web service. Both files ultimately can be quite large like up to 20 MB and also it is unpredictable when these files will be created because they are generated by the user. Therefore it could be like 2 minutes between the time when this process occurs or it could be several all in the same second. The system is not like crazy in the sense that it could be like hundreds of these operations in the same second but it could be several.

My instinct says to solve it by:

- Creating a separate thread when the process begins.
- Read the first file.
- Do the data transformation.
- Write the contents to the new file.
- Send the file to the service.
- Delete the created file.

Am I missing something? Is there a best practice to tackle this kind of issue?

Comment: Why create a file if you can avoid it? Just transform the data and stream it to the receiving service.

Comment: Depending on how many files are being processed, you can store that data all in memory, it doesn't have to be a file on disk

Comment: I cant avoid it.... I have to in the beginning get the data from the file... And the service accepts the file. This process is the middle point and I have to send it as a file.

Comment: *"I have looked at examples that tell best practices for ..."*  That's typical of so-called "best practices".  They don't actually take account of the particular requirements.  Read this: http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question you should ask is weather you *need* to write the file to the disk in the first place. Even if you are supposed to send a file to a consumer at the end of your processing phase, you could keep the file contents in memory and send that. The consumer doesn't care weather the file is stored on disk or not, since it only receives an *array of bytes* with the file contents.

The only scenario in which it would make sense to store the file on disk would be if you would communicate between your processes via disk files (i.e. your producer writes a file to disk, sends some notification to your consumer and afterwards your consumer reads the file from disk - for example based on a file name it receives from the notification).

Regarding I/O best practices, make sure you use ***buffers*** to read (and potentially write) files. This could greatly reduce the memory overhead (since you would end up keeping only a chunk instead of the whole 20 MB file in memory at a given moment).

Regarding adding multiple threads, you should test weather that improves your application performance or not. If your application is already I/O intensive, adding multiple threads will result in adding even more contention on your I/O streams, which would result in a performance degradation.

Answer (score 0):

Given the description you have given, I think you should perform the operations for each file on one thread; i.e. on thread will download the file, process it and then upload the results.

If you need parallelism, then implement the download / process / upload as a `Runnable` and submit the tasks to an `ExecutorService` with a bounded thread pool.  And tune the size of the thread pool.  (That's easy if you expose the thread pool size as a config property.)

Why this way?

1. It is simple.  Minimal synchronization is required.
2. One of the three subtasks is likely to be your performance bottleneck.  So by combining all three into a single task, you avoid the situation where the non-bottleneck tasks get too far ahead.  And if you get too far ahead on some of the subtasks you risk running out of (local) disk space.

---

I'm going to contradict what Alex Rolea said about buffering.  Yes, it *may help*.  But in on a modern (e.g. Linux) operating system on a typical modern machine, memory <-> disk I/O is unlikely to be the main bottleneck.  It is more likely that the bottleneck will be network I/O or server-side I/O performance (especially if the server is serving other clients at the same time.)

So, I would not *prematurely* tune the buffering.  Get the system working, benchmark it, profile / analyze it, and **based on those results** figure out where the real bottlenecks are and how best to address them.

Part of the solution may be to not use disk at all.  (I know you think you need to, but unless your server and its protocols are really strange, you should be able to stream the data to the server out of memory on the client side.)

Answer (score 0):

Without the full details of the situation, a problem like this may be better solved with existing software such as [Apache NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org/):

> An easy to use, powerful, and reliable system to process and distribute data.

It's very good at picking up files, transforming them, and putting them somewhere else (and sending emails, and generating analytics, and...). NiFi is a very powerful tool, but may be overkill if you're needs are just a couple of files given the additional set-up.